# Material name is grayed out in Shader editor; cannot rename it

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes

This is an issue I have never encountered before:  I have a material where I cannot change its name, duplicate it, remove it, or make it a fake user. Otherwise, I can still edit it in the Node editor and the material renders fine. Why?

Other weird things: This material links to two bitmaps, but it would not let me edit the bitmap settings unless I made them unique by clicking on the number of users in the texture box; never had that happen before.

If I try to locate the source bitmap from the texture box, it does not seem to know where the texture is, despite my repeatedly reconnecting to it. What's going on? Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.5.0, Windows 11

[image: example]

Comment: You have pinned the material. See the pin icon right next to the 2nd arrow in your screenshot. Just click it.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!!